# DAX month this year vs month last year using most recent month from selected months filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

If I have a filter and January and February selected, how would I be able to create a month this year versus the same month last year MEASURE that will automatically use February only instead of January and February?

Note that I cannot unselect January because I am using YTD last year vs YTD this year in the same pivot table.

[image]

I am looking for something like:

=CALCULATE(SUM(Brand_Sales_2020_2021[Sales]), 'Calendar'[Month] = "The most recent month from the selection in the filter")

Comment: As your month filter showing only Month names, how you defining years for them? And what is the logic for calculating value last Year?

Comment: YTD 2020, YTD 2021, YTD Diff are measures e.g. CALCULATE(SUM(Sales_2019_2020_2021[Sales]), 'Calendar'[Year] = 2021), I just want Same Month 2020 and Same Month 2021 to show the max month from the filter selection. For example, January and Feb are selected then the Feb 2020 and the Feb 2021 sales will show on those columns not January and Feb. Logic is to see the growth rate.